# Full path to import works but file reference doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-behave

Looking at [this](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial06.html) `behave` tutorial I find that in file `features/steps/step_tutorial06.py`, if I use `from company_model import CompanyModel` as is in the example I get `Unresolved reference 'company_model'` but if I use `from features.steps.company_model import CompanyModel` it works. Why is this and is there any way around this?

This is in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Relative import. This is because PyCharm launches python from Project directory and not from the directory you are working in.

However, to get rid of this long `from features.steps.company_model import CompanyModel`, you can use `from .company_model import CompanyModel` since both files are in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

because project structure starts from the folder features in pycharm. Hence it is appearing in that format.